Excel, how to find which groups in one column have different values in another column
I want to see from the following table, which AAA numbers have different values in EEE.



AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
EEE




11
0
A
10-1-2020
#1


11
0
B
11-2-2020
#1


11
0
C
14-3-2020
#1


11
0
D
15-4-2020
#1


22
0
A
15-3-2024
#2


22
0
B
20-3-2024
#2


22
0
B
23-3-2024
#2


22
0
C
24-3-2024
#2


22
0
D
24-3-2024
#2


33
0
A
2-3-2022
#1


33
0
B
3-3-2022
#1


33
0
C
4-3-2022
#1


33
0
D
5-3-2022
#1


33
1
A
6-3-2022
#2


33
1
B
7-3-2022
#2


33
1
B
8-3-2022
#2


33
1
B
9-3-2022
#2


33
1
B
10-3-2022
#2


33
1
C
11-3-2022
#2


33
1
C
12-3-2022
#2


33
1
C
13-3-2022
#2


33
1
D
14-3-2022
#2


44
0
A
6-8-2022
#1


44
0
A
3-11-2022
#1


44
0
A
31-1-2023
#1


44
0
A
30-4-2023
#1


44
0
B
28-7-2023
#1


44
0
B
25-10-2023
#1


44
0
B
22-1-2024
#1


44
0
C
20-4-2024
#1


44
0
D
18-7-2024
#1


44
0
D
15-10-2024
#1


44
1
A
12-1-2025
#2


44
1
B
11-4-2025
#2


44
1
C
9-7-2025
#2


44
1
D
6-10-2025
#2


44
2
A
3-1-2026
#2


44
2
B
2-4-2026
#2


44
2
C
30-6-2026
#2


44
2
D
27-9-2026
#2



In this example, AAA=11 has only #1 in EEE. But AAA=44 has #1 and #2 in column EEE. I want to list which AAA values have different values in EEE. And make a list of the AAA values with their one, two or more values in EEE
A list would like



11
#1




22
#2


33
#1


33
#2


44
#1


44
#2



Or something similar. How can I do this automated and not manually?

This is not a script writing service. Show us your work, and you can get help where there are difficulties.

I suggest you try Excel Power Query:
Select your table, go to Data tab > Get & Transform Data group > From Table/Range.
Go to Home tab > Transform group > Group By. Then you may group by "AAA" and "EEE", then show "All Rows", click "OK".

You will get a table like following image, delete the "Count" column.

At last, please click "Close and Load" > "Close and Load To", export the table to one sheet.
